# how to print tensorflow graph to svg or png file?

Tags: svg, tensorflow, graph, png

I know that I can use tensorboard to visualize graphs. But in some cases, I may not want to open tensorboard is there a way to directly generate a png of svg file to visualize tensorflow? Thanks.

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    x = tf.constant(3.)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(tf.get_default_graph())
```